# How to make the gx command work for URLs in Vim on XFCE4 Desktop?

Tags: vim

With GVim on my Windows 7 system, if I press gx while the cursor is on an URL, it launches the URL in Firefox (my default browser on Windows).

However, when I do the same on my XFCE4 Desktop on Debian 8.3 Linux system, pressing gx does nothing at all.

I am using GVim (Vim 7.4) on both systems.

The `:let g:netrw_browsex_viewer` command returns `E121: Undefined variable: g:netrw_browsex_viewer` on both systems.

I tried entering the `:let g:netrw_browsex_viewer= "xdg-open"` command on the Linux system, but it didn't help at all.

I have two questions:

1. Why does the `gx` command work for URLs on the Windows system but not on XFCE4 desktop on the Debian Linux system even though `g:netrw_browsex_viewer` is undefined in both?
2. How can I make the `gx` command work for URLs on XFCE4 desktop on the Debian Linux system?

Comment: What happen when you run `xdg-open http://google.com/` in a terminal on your XFCE system?

Comment: @SatoKatsura `xdg-open http://google.com/` launches Google in Firefox. If there is no Firefox running, a new Firefox instance is launched. If Firefox is already running, then a new tab is opened in the existing instance.

Comment: Ok, what happens if you run this from GVim on your XFCE system: `:call system('xdg-open http://google.com/')`?

Comment: @SatoKatsura Running `:call system('xdg-open http://google.com/')` from GVim on XFCE also launches Firefox (or a Firefox tab) to display the URL.

Comment: Then adding `let g:netrw_browsex_viewer="xdg-open"` to your `vimrc` should work.  If it doesn't then you didn't add it to the right file.

Comment: @SatoKatsura I tried two things. I entered `:let g:netrw_browsex_viewer="xdg-open"` in command-line mode in Vim itself. The `gx` command did nothing after that. I also entered `let g:netrw_browsex_viewer="xdg-open"` in ~/.vimrc. The `gx` command still did not work. I have other commands such as `colorscheme darkblue`, etc. in the same file which work fine.

Comment: Then perhaps post a bug report to `vim_dev`?  The author of `netrw` is seen there once in a while.

Comment: http://vi.stackexchange.com/q/5032/71 I opened a [bug](https://bugzilla.xfce.org/show_bug.cgi?id=12251) for that.

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt In your answer to that question, someone requested if you could explain why `setsid` fixed the problem? Could you please share those details? By the way, your answer did fix the issue on my system. Thanks!

Comment: @LoneLearner I don't remember the details, sorry.

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt Ideally this question should be closed as a duplicate of  http://vi.stackexchange.com/q/5032/71 but I can't vote to do that because the other question is on a different StackExchange site. So if you could post your comment as an answer, I can accept your answer, award you the bounty points and close this question.

Comment: I am not paying attention to comments either, as I didn't see the other comments explaining setsid.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Normally, the following command should work, and it does work when executing Vim 7.4.576 within Xfce terminal (xfce4-terminal 0.6.3).

```
:let g:netrw_browsex_viewer="xdg-open"
```

But the above command does not work in GVim 7.4.576 in Xfce 4.10 due to *[Bug 12251](https://bugzilla.xfce.org/show_bug.cgi?id=12251) - exo-open URL does nothing from gvim*.

A workaround suggested by [Christian Brabandt](https://stackoverflow.com/users/789222/) that works for me is the following.

```
:let g:netrw_browsex_viewer="setsid xdg-open"
```

Answer (score -2):

I should read more carefully!!

You are using GVim.  There is an [open bug issue](https://bugzilla.xfce.org/show_bug.cgi?id=12251) with the gx command with GVim using Xfce4.  It doesn't look like it's been fixed.  But from some discussions, it appears you can circumvent the issue by using:

```
let g:netrw_browsex_viewer="setsid xdg-open"
```

Comment: In the discussion in the comment that follows the question, I have explained that xdg-open is present on my system and it works fine.

Comment: Yes, I overlooked that; but at any rate xfce4 doesn't use xdg-open; it uses exo-open.  Did you try exo-open?